# How to convert string list to float in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, floating-point

I have a list of prices in my training set which are:

```
print(Y_train[:5])
-->["12,702.25", "221.45", "3,173.0", "794.0", "1,83,825.75"]
```

I want to convert this string list to a float list where I want these commas(',') to be excluded as well. How can I do it?

The output has to be in like:

```
print(Y_train[:5])
-->[12702.25, 221.45, 3173.0, 794.0, 183825.75]
```

Comment: Try `[float(i.replace(',', '')) for i in l]`?

Answer (score 0):

Chris proposed the solution first in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927528/how-to-convert-string-list-to-float-in-python/58927671?noredirect=1#comment104115650_58927528), so full credit to him, I just want to put an end to these shameful answers.

```py
raw_str_list = ['1,234.5', '372,737,000.993']
res_list = [float(curr.replace(',', '')) for curr in raw_str_list]
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple what you have to do is add a new list and convert it into a float for example `newList = [float(i) for i in Y_train]`

Comment: This ignores OP’s problem completely.

Comment: will you explain to me how it will ignore?

Comment: Did you read the post? Have you tried running your solution? Also, your variable `newList` should be called `new_list`, please use proper Python style.

Comment: This will not work as it will give you a value error, because of the commas that are there in between. I specified it extensively.